# Как считать данные из файла в коллекцию java с помощью стримов?

Tags: java

Есть файл, там названия городов просто. Нужно считать данные, добавить их в коллекцию и уже потом дальше выполнять задания с ними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `lines` из хелпера `Files`, чтобы получить stream:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Или, чтобы сразу получить коллекцию - `readAllLines`:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"))
```

Источник: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-